# Webstorm Typescript loading modules results in Unexpected token import

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, webstorm, node-modules, es6-module-loader

So before I start following is a brief of the environment

1. IDE: Webstorm, latest release
2. es6 is installed and enabled
3. babel is installed. babel file watcher is installed
4. Typescripts is installed

What I am trying to do is to create a module and then import it and use, however I always get different errors. Following is a list of files that I do have and its content

1. staf.ts

   ```
   export class Staf {
   StaffNo: number;
   Username: string;
   Firstname: string;
   Lastname: string;
   Password: string;
   Type: string;
   Program: array<string>;
   }
   ```

Webstorm underlines the word Staf with the folllowing error

```
cannot compile external modules unless the '--module' flag is provided
```

2. login.js

   ```
   import Staff from 'Staf';

   $(document).ready(function(){
   console.log('hello');

   var staff = [];

   $.getJSON('data/staff.json', function(data) {
   $.each(data, function (i, record) {
   staff.push(record);
   });
   });

   console.log(staff);

   $('.btn').click(function(){
   var name = $('input[aria-describedby=basic-addon-username]').val();
   var pass = $('input[aria-describedby=basic-addon-passwor]').val();

   $.each(staff, function(i, data){
   if( (data.Username == name || data.Firstname == name) && data.Password == pass){
   console.log("hi");
   $($('.input-group')).addClass('has-success')
   window.location.href = "./actions.html";
   }
   })

   $($('.input-group')).addClass('has-error');
   $('.help-block').toggle();
   //$('.bg-danger').show();

   })

   })
   ```
3. Login.html

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
    <title>STARS - Login</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
   <!--<script src="node_modules/babel-browser/browser.js"></script>-->
   <script src="js/login.js"></script>
   <script src="node_modules/systemjs/node_modules/es6-module-loader/src/system.js"></script>
   <script>
       System.config({
           baseURL: 'node_modules/babel-browser/browser.js',
           // or 'traceur' or 'typescript'
           transpiler: 'babel',
           // or traceurOptions or typescriptOptions
           babelOptions: {

           }
       });

       // loads /app/main.js
       System.import('lgoin.js');

   </script>
   </head>

    <body>

    </body>
   </html>
   ```

When I try to run that I get three errors

```
  1. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
  2. Uncaught ReferenceError: Loader is not defined
  3. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined
```

Now I have tried to install babel, babel-cli and babel-preset-es2015
However noting leads to a breakthrough to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

> cannot compile external modules unless the '--module' flag is provided

The typescript target is very likely not set to ES6

Create a [`tsconfig.json`](https://github.com/Microsoft/typescript/wiki/tsconfig.json) file withe the `target` set to ES6.

In Webstorm -> Preferences -> Languages -> Typescript, select `use tsconfig.json` file

**EDIT: see comments**

`staf.ts` should be

```
class Staf {
...
}

export default Staf
```

`login.js` should be

```
import Staf from './staf'
```

(note the './staf')

Comment: I have followed you instruction. The same errors remain, plus when I try to run the typescript compiler I get an error "Cannot find name 'array' " ... any ideas ?

Comment: Try `Array<string>` (capital A) or simply `string[]`

Comment: Great this helps. But now I get another error s2304 cannot find name 'module'

Comment: I cannot see any modue in what you showed here. Also your js seem to refer to `staff` as an array an your ts to `Staf` as a class. The relationship between the two is unclear

Comment: staff was supposed be an array of Staf .. how would be the right way to declare it ?

Comment: The import statement is for a default export of Staff. See Edits in response above